# How can i run a function if the value of a html is under a certain number

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools

Im trying to create a script that will run a function if a value is above 0 and refresh the page if its under 0 using html.
Im trying to run this script in chrome dev tools

here is my script so far. var is erroring.

```html
function Above()
    var text = document.querySelector("#belowcard > h3:nth-child(2)");
    if (text == &#60) {
     location.reload();
    }
    else{
     PowerP();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use setInterval to schedule a timer

Answer (score 0):

To execute the function only once, use the setTimeout() method instead.

To clear an interval, use the id returned from setInterval():

```
myInterval = setInterval(function, milliseconds);
```

Then you can to stop the execution by calling clearInterval():

```
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const numberEl=document.getElementByYouSelector;
function reloadPage(){
const value=Number(numberEl.textContent);
if(value<0) window.location.reload();
}
```